# how can I test if any of my HTCondor jobs returned with a non-zero error code?

Tags: condor

I have a script running `condor_submit` for a batch of 25 jobs, `condor_wait` for them all to complete and then another `condor_submit` for another batch pf 25 jobs.

I want to make sure non of the first 25 jobs failed with `Normal termination (return value 127)` (any non-zero return value).

How can I easily do this? 
Or if that's impossible I'm also willing to wrap my job executable in a script that will fail them in case they return non-zero - but I'm not sure how to fail a HTCondor job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use condor_history http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/manual/current/condor_history.html

If you run the following command:

```
condor_history USERNAME -af clusterId ExitStatus
```

It will return a space separated list of

JobId ExitStatus

It also supports other options other than just passing USERNAME.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem is to use the condor_dagman tool.  With dagman, you list the dependencies between your jobs, and dagman automatically submits a job when all the jobs which is depends on have completed.  No need to run condor_wait or look at exit codes.